# JavaScript eval function can not perform operation on two numbers

Tags: javascript, eval

```
alert('The result is ${eval('${num1} ${operator} ${num2}')}');
```

eval() function used to perform operation on two numbers (num1 and num2 are numbers and operator is "+ , - , * , /") but I got problem in the code. is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Template literals use `\``, not the `'`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: (1) don't use `alert`, use `console.log` and look at your dev tools console. Because `alert` can't show the majority of JS data types, it can only show strings. (2) why are you using `eval` at all? If you want to parse and evaluate math statements, just use something like [math.js](https://mathjs.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
alert(`The result is ${eval(`${num1} ${operator} ${num2}`)}`);
```

Backticks instead of single quotes when using template literals.
That said, I would caution against using eval(), as it can execute arbitrary code and might pose security risks if used with user input.